# Dropdown Menu doesn't update textfield values in Chrome, but works fine in Firefox and IE

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, menu

I am making a simple calculator web application using HTML and Javascript. I will style it once I get it to work.

Here is the link to the source code in Javascript:
[Calculator, unnecessary parts blanked out](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1tUY5bVx7UVT0hkYl9abFN2bjQ/view?usp=sharing)

**My problem:**

The calculator has certain percentage values depending on the calendar year, hence changing the year should change the values in the input text fields.

This works fine in Firefox and IE (once you enable blocked content) but refuses to work in Chrome. I've released that Chrome has tighter security policies, so I added a document event handler but this still does not work while using Chrome. I've attached the relevant code please help this is driving me mad.

Answer (score 0):

The event listens to `click` not `change`, try this.

```
document.getElementById('year').addEventListener('change', handleOnclick);
```

Comment: hi, altered it to 'change' but its the same result, it still works under firefox but not in chrome. I need this to work in all major web browsers, (ff, chrome, ie) at minimum thanks for your comment